# How do I format time using Obj C like "2m 6s"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date-formatting

I'm storing time in seconds and would like to display them in minutes and seconds like "2m 6s".  Ideally this would be done with localization. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @JoshCaswell That is not the format I'm after at all.  Should I edit my question to be clearer?  I only want minutes and seconds with an 'm' and an 's' following the numbers.

Comment: No, you should [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+nsdate), read [the Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4), and try something yourself. We have enough questions about `NSDateFormatter` here; everybody should be able to figure out their own pet format at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really boils down to standard math.

If you have the seconds, just divide it by 60 to get the number of minutes. For the remaining seconds, simply take the *modulus* of the total amount of seconds by 60.

e.g.

```
int minutes = seconds / 60;
int seconds = seconds % 60;
NSString *formattedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%im %is", minutes, seconds];
```

It's actually quite simple!

Comment: You could also do this in one step with the library function [`div()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/div.3.html).